# How could you wipe out all life from the universe?

Tags: science-fiction, physics, universe, astrophysics

If you had as many resources as you needed, obviously making A LOT of assumptions about physics, how could you semi-realistically kill all living creatures in the universe?

Comment: Welcome to the site Arthur. Please take the [tour] and at your leisure browse the [help] to get the hang of how we work here. Then perhaps you can [edit] your post so include some sort of worldbuilding context, as the current parameters you've supplied are minimalist at best rendering your question too broad at present.

Comment: When you say "the universe" do you mean the visible universe at this present time viewed from here? Does it matter if you wreck space-time in the process? How long must the process take (ie. does just *waiting* for the heat-death count), or what time scale are you working to? What technology level are you at? It would help enormously if you were to clarify.

Comment: Assume that you had a time machine and travel to the heat death of the universe. This is too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: Step 1. Acquire Infinity Gauntlet

Comment: I suggest you to go and read HALO (or play it), their aliens have already managed to do so.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal Halo 1 was amazing. Still worth a play.

Comment: See also: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201743/seeking-good-physical-candidates-for-total-collapse-of-the-universe-we-live-in

Answer (score 3):

Trigger a [Vacuum decay event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum).

In Quantum Field Theory, there's an idea that the vacuum state of the Universe is not actually at zero energy level. Instead, its at a "false zero", meaning that it could decay into a lower energy level.

[image]

If a more stable energy level for the vacuum is achieved, then this would expand outward across the Universe at the speed of light causing the complete destruction of barionic matter (and all life) as we know it.

Kurzgesagt made a video on this topic that explains the idea more graphically: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijFm6DxNVyI

Answer (score 2):

**1. Change the laws of physics**

There are four fundamental forces in the universe: strong nuclear force, weak nuclear force, electromagnetism, and gravity. [You could fundamentally change one of these laws, upsetting the balance of nature.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_universe) That change for *hand waving reasons* propagates out from the epicenter at the speed of light (or faster than the speed of light), a wave that wreaks havoc as it goes.

If you cancel the strong nuclear force then all subatomic particles in the universe disassociate into quarks and normal matter "dissolves". If you muddle around with the weak nuclear or electromagnetic forces then atoms disassociate and fly into pieces, and the world dies in a radioactive flash. If you cancel gravity then the suns stop shining, rocky planets break apart, and people are left to contemplate a slow death.

**2. A new inflationary bubble**

[You kick off a new big bang in normal space](http://www.worldsciencefestival.com/2014/09/will-higgs-boson-destroy-universe-cosmic-death-bubble/), which rapidly expands and annihilates the existing galaxy, replacing it with a new one.

**3. More realistic with near-term technology: von-Neumann murder probes**

John von-Neumann [proposed space probes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft) that would travel to distant stars, and at each star they would create a copy of themselves, and the two copies would go their separate ways. This starts out slow, but the number of probes multiplies exponentially. Eventually, every star in the galaxy, and eventually the universe, is visited. This works because each probe only has to make one copy of itself in each system it encounters, which distributes the work. It's not feasible for one planet to make a billion probes, but if each probe doubles, then:

- After one generation there are two probes
- After two generations there are four probes
- After three generations there are eight probes
- After four generations there are sixteen probes
- After ten generations there are 1024 probes
- After twenty generations there are about a million probes
- After thirty generations there are about a billion probes
- After forty generations there are about a trillion probes
- After N generations there are about 2^N probes

(Assuming no probes are lost to breakdowns or hostile activity.)

The only difference is that your probes also kill everything they find.

These are computer probes, so even travelling at sub-light-speed they can spend a long time just waiting out the journey between stars as long as they were suitably capable of maintaining themselves. They could even transit between galaxies.

One kink here is that presumably some of the universe exists beyond the boundary of the observable universe, and due to inflation those portions of the universe will never be reachable from our portion of the universe without faster than light travel. But, most of your readers are not going to glom onto that particular flaw.

Answer (score 1):

The only plausible way to do this is to physically end the Universe. And the only even semi plausible idea is the idea that we are currently in a "false vacuum" and there is a means to create the "true vacuum", which will expand outward at the speed of light and destroy everything in its path, right down to subatomic particles.

[Vacuum decay](https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/vacuum-decay-ultimate-catastrophe) is a strange and esoteric topic, and difficult to summarize in a few short paragraphs. This quote is perhaps the most succinct that I could find:

> [Q]uantum fields (which are basically a set of rules that the tiniest bits of matter need to obey) want to move from a high energy state to a lower energy state. When they are in the lowest energy state possible, they're stable. The fear is that one of these quantum fields, the Higgs field, is not actually stable, but rather exists in a "false vacuum." This means it still contains potential energy. If this energy was somehow triggered, it would create a rolling tide of destruction, called a stable Higgs field, moving at the speed of light, vaporizing everything in its path, and leaving in its wake a void where physics as we know it would cease to exist and life would be impossible.

https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a23487/false-vacuum-apocalypse/

To fully unpack this would require an understanding of quantum fields, what they do and how thier energy levels are calculated and what sort of events could trigger a collapse to the lower "true vacuum". This is sometimes described as being in a divot on the side of a valley. So long as we remain in the divot, we will not roll down to the bottom of the valley, but a sufficiently high energy event, or even quantum tunneling could trigger the event.

[image]

*Note the energy levels - 10^15 GEV is a huge number*

So by triggering Vacuum decay and collapsing the universe to the true vacuum, you would fundamentally undo everything, including the laws of physics, making life impossible in the new universe.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

ALL living creatures have existed across a span of time. Many are already dead, and cannot be killed now. I have seen living things die, and I'm pretty sure that you (or your proxy) were not there. Others will emerge after your murderous cohort has passed.

But let's set that aside...and take the much more limited case of:

- Killing all living creatures that happen to be alive when and where you discover them, and
- You have the capacity to discover all creatures in your area (they cannot hide from you), and
- You can travel the universe at will.

These capacities seem to require (effectively) infinite knowledge and (effectively) infinite energy, or at least most of the knowledge and energy available in the universe. (This makes it more of a philosophy question than a science-fiction question.)

In a rather meaningful sense, you must *become* the universe in order to kill the other creatures inhabiting it. In which case, universe, I want my stolen bicycle back, please. The white one, taken in 2005.